# TextBox default text on load, empty textbox on focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a text box:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" 
            BorderColor="Silver" Height="20px" Style="margin-left: 6px" Width="136px" OnFocus = "onfocus(); return false;"></asp:TextBox>

function onfocus(){ document.getElementById('<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>').value = "";}
```

with default text on it, on page load:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // By Default the date of submission is set to current date. // 
                TextBox3.Text = "Enter Member ID";
            }
```

When the client clicks on the textbox, I want the default text to be cleared (empty textbox), so that the client can enter the actual ID and not have to manually delete the default text.

However the method I am visualizing, isn't working with the code that I have written.

Comment: you can consider to use html5's `placeholder`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about you just use a `placeholder` on your input:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" placeholder="Member ID" .... ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: This doesn't work with IE. 

apparently you have to use this:-

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js

still cant figure how to use that library and edit the code. Can you help?